# local JSON file and data in controller method

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sapui5

This is my code in controller `init` method:

```
 mycontroller = this

 var data = [{
     "No": "456980",
     "Updates": [{
         "Test": "abc"
     }, {
         "Test": "bca"
     }, {
         "Test": "dbd"
     }]
 }, {
     "No": "456980",
     "Updates": [{
         "Test": "abc"
     }, {
         "Test": "bca"
     }, {
         "Test": "dbd"
     }]
 }, {
     "No": "456980",
     "Updates": [{
         "Test": "abc"
     }, {
         "Test": "bca"
     }, {
         "Test": "dbd"
     }]
 }]
 var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
 oModel.setData(data);

 //set this model to list control having custom list as aggregation
 mycontroller.List1.setModel(oModel);

 mycontroller.List1.bindAggregation("items", {
     path: "/",
     template: mycontroller.List1_template
 });

 var ListItems = P1Notificationcontroller.list1.getItems();
 var ListLength = ListItems.length;

 for (var i = 0; i < ListLength; i++) {
     var control = "status_vbox-list1-" + i;
     sap.ui.getCore().byId(control).bindAggregation("items", {
         path: "Updates",
         template: new sap.m.Text('', {
             text: '{Update}'
         })
     });
 }
```

view declaration create content

```
oController.List1 = new sap.m.List("List1", {
    headerDesign: sap.m.ListHeaderDesign.Standard
});
oController.List1_template = new sap.m.CustomListItem("McustomlistItem", {
            content: [
                new sap.m.VBox('', {
                    items: [
                        new sap.m.Text('', {
                            text: "{No}"
                        })
                        new sap.m.VBox('status_vbox', {
                            items: []
                        })
                    ]
                }));
```

The above code in view and controllers `init` method works perfectly fine the items in custom list `VBox` are aggregated from update array in data.

when the same data when maintained in local json file &
by using this line of code

```
 var jsonmodel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("mockData/local.json");
 mycontroller.List1.setModel(jsonmodel)
```

the loop for `VBox` is failing because we are not able to loop the object .

when i console.log of both models OData attribute of one model is showing as Array and other as object, because of object the loop is not happening

how can we maintain the same data in local json file to loop the updates attribute to the `VBox` in custom list item as above.

Comment: Use `[loadData](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html#loadData)` method with `async` as `false`

Comment: rayon can you let me know where i can include this method  clearly in my code?

Comment: Go through the provided URL..

Comment: @Rayon the provided URL doesnt work. youre missing the hash - https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html#loadData

Comment: @user3349850, https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel.html#loadData

Comment: @user3349850 - just on another note - the code you have above is not JSON but a javascript array. Is your JSON valid and is it loading correctly? you can check your [json here](http://jsonlint.com/) and check if its loading in your developer console

Comment: @Rayon yeah I know, if you noticed I included it in my comment, theres no need to post it an additional 2 times.

Answer (score 1):

the issue resolved by calling jquery ajax call to fill the local json model as below

```
  jQuery.ajax({
            url: "mockData/Local.json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {        

            var jsonmodel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                jsonmodel.setData(data);
                sap.ui.getCore().setModel(jsonmodel,'testmodel');

            mycontroller.List1.setModel(jsonmodel)


               }
```